# How to convert a string with "[]" into an integer array

Tags: java, string, get

I have two strings:

```
String s1 = "[143, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 157, 158, 159, 162, 163, 164]";

String s2 = "[20, 35, 74, 78, 124, 125, 126, 127, 131, 132, 143, 144, 145, 146]";
```

All I want to do is find the smallest common number in this two strings. So I first displace the "[]" symbol, and extract numbers from string into integers. Then use a loop to find the smallest common number.The program is as below:

```
s1 = s1.replace("[",""); 
s1 = s1.replace("]","");
String [] band = s1.split(",");     
s2 = s2.replace("[",""); 
s2 = s2.replace("]","");
String [] hotel = s1.split(",");    
System.out.println( EarliestCommonSlot(hotel,band) );
```

The EarliestCommonSlot() is defined as below:

```
public static int EarliestCommonSlot(String [] a1, String [] b1){
    int i=0,j=0;
    int common = -1;
    int [] a = new int [a1.length];
    int [] b = new int [b1.length];

    for(i = 0;i < a1.length;i++)
    {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt( a1[i]);
        System.out.println(a1[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0;i < b1.length;i++)
    {
        b[i] = Integer.parseInt( b1[i]);
        System.out.println(b1[i]);
    }
    i = 0; j=0;
    while ( i< a.length && j < b.length){
        if ( a[i] == b[j] ){
            common = a[i]; break;
        }
        if ( a[i] < b[j] ){
            i++;
        }
        else j++;
    }
    return common;
}
```

But when I run the program, it has the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 143"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at ClientReserve.EarliestCommonSlot(ClientReserve.java:39)
    at ClientReserve.main(ClientReserve.java:179)
```

Why is that? How could I fix that?

Comment: The leading space is the problem. Try ``Integer.parseInt( a1[i].trim());`` or make sure the splitted strings dont contain any spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
s1.replace("]"," "); // This replaces the bracket with a space.
                     // The number with the space will emit the error
```

Use :

```
s1.replace("]","");//This replaces the bracket with an empty string.
```

---

New code:

```
s1 = s1.replace("[",""); 
s1 = s1.replace("]","");
String [] band = s1.split(", ");     
s2 = s2.replace("[",""); 
s2 = s2.replace("]","");
String [] hotel = s1.split(", ");    //Comma and a space. Thanks to SaviourSelf
System.out.println( EarliestCommonSlot(hotel,band) );
```

Comment: @NUO Use `.trim()` to remove leading and trailing spaces from Strings.

Comment: @NUO You have to use `replace("]","");` for both Strings `s1` and `s2` and for both the brackets.

Comment: The numbers are delimited by a comma and a space. All integers will have a space before them, not just the first.

Comment: @SaviourSelf Thanks for that. Didn't notice that. Editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the white spaces from the strings in array. That can be done by

`st.replaceAll("\\s+","")` and `st.replaceAll("\\s","")`

in the error itself it is showing that 143 is having space in prefix. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 143"

Answer (score 1):

use the trim() method

```
String s1 = "[143, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 157, 158, 159, 162, 163, 164]";

    String s2 = "[20, 35, 74, 78, 124, 125, 126, 127, 131, 132, 143, 144, 145, 146]";
    s1 = s1.replace("[",""); 
    s1 = s1.replace("]","");
    String [] band = s1.split(",");     
    s2 = s2.replace("[",""); 
    s2 = s2.replace("]","");
    String [] hotel = s1.split(",");    
    System.out.println( EarliestCommonSlot(hotel,band) );



 public static int EarliestCommonSlot(String [] a1, String [] b1){
        int i=0,j=0;
        int common = -1;
        int [] a = new int [a1.length];
        int [] b = new int [b1.length];

        for(i = 0;i < a1.length;i++)
        {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt( a1[i].trim());
            System.out.println(a1[i]);
        }
        for(i = 0;i < b1.length;i++)
        {
            b[i] = Integer.parseInt( b1[i].trim());
            System.out.println(b1[i]);
        }
        i = 0; j=0;
        while ( i< a.length && j < b.length){
            if ( a[i] == b[j] ){
                common = a[i]; break;
            }
            if ( a[i] < b[j] ){
                i++;
            }
            else j++;
        }
        return common;
    }
```

I have run this method and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {


  public static void main(String[] args) {



String s1 = "[143, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 157, 158, 159, 162, 163, 164]";

String s2 = "[20, 35, 74, 78, 124, 125, 126, 127, 131, 132, 143, 144, 145, 146]";
      s1 = s1.replace("[",""); 
      s1 = s1.replace("]","");
      s1 = s1.replace(" ","");
      String [] band = s1.split(",");     
      s2 = s2.replace("[",""); 
      s2 = s2.replace("]","");

      String [] hotel = s1.split(",");    
      System.out.println( EarliestCommonSlot(hotel,band) );
  }
  public static int EarliestCommonSlot(String [] a1, String [] b1){
        int i=0,j=0;
        int common = -1;
        int [] a = new int [a1.length];
        int [] b = new int [b1.length];

        for(i = 0;i < a1.length;i++)
        {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt( a1[i]);
            System.out.println(a1[i]);
        }
        for(i = 0;i < b1.length;i++)
        {
            b[i] = Integer.parseInt( b1[i]);
            System.out.println(b1[i]);
        }
        i = 0; j=0;
        while ( i< a.length && j < b.length){
            if ( a[i] == b[j] ){
                common = a[i]; break;
            }
            if ( a[i] < b[j] ){
                i++;
            }
            else j++;
        }
        return common;
    }    
   }
```